# smooth quotient out of a singular variety?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, finite-groups, singularity-theory

If $X$ is a smooth quasi-projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$ and $G$ is a finite group acting faithfully on $X$, then the Shepard-Todd theorem gives us some criterion for $X/G$ to be smooth.

My question goes a little bit backward. Assume that $X$ is a variety (irreducible, reduced and separated scheme of finite typer over $\mathbb{C}$) with a faithful action of finite group $G$ on it.

Assume that the quotient $X/G$ is smooth. Can we say something on $X$ (is it Cohen-Macaulay?) Or on the quotient morphism $p : X \rightarrow X/G$ (is it flat?).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example: Take $\mathbb C^2$ minus the origin and identify the points $(1,1)$ and $(-1,-1)$ and let this be $X$. Then $G=\mathbb Z/2$ acts by $(x,y) \mapsto (-x,-y)$ and the quotient is smooth, but $X$ is not Cohen-Macauley (two planes intersecting in a point is not Cohen-Macaulay). The quotient map is not flat either, since a finite morphism with smooth target is flat iff the source is CM.

Comment: This seems to be a nice answer, but could you explain why the quotient is smooth at the image of $(1,1) = (-1,-1)$?

Comment: Is it also clear that your $X$ is quasi-projective?

Comment: If you consider $\mathbb C^2 \setminus \{0,0\}$ and divide by $\pm 1$, the quotient is just $\mathbb C^2 \setminus \{0,0\}$. The same is true for $X / \pm 1$; informally, $(1,1)$ and $(-1,-1)$ were going to be identified in the quotient anyway, so it does not matter if we identify them before quotienting. Yes, it should be clear that it is quasi-projective, but a direct argument escapes me at the moment. You can prove it by a nuke: contracting a closed subscheme of an affine variety to a point produces a new affine variety, so $\mathbb C^2$ with two points identified is affine...

Comment: ... and the nuke is in a paper of Karl Schwede on gluing and pushouts of schemes.

Comment: Yes, but it seems to me that in Schwede's paper you are quoting 
it is claimed that contracting a subscheme of an affine scheme to a point one obtains a scheme, not necessarily an *affine* scheme. For instance, he shows that contracting a line in $\mathbb{A}^2$ the resulting scheme is *not* noetherian, hence it cannot be $\rm{Spec}\, A$ where $A$ is an noetherian ring.

For this reason, I'm still not convinced that this argument shows the quasi-projectivity of $X$.

Comment: OK. So I would gladly accept Dan's answer, if I can be sure that $X$ is a quasi-projective variety.

Comment: A  variation of this answer in order to satisfy Libli's request that the example be quasi-projective: take $X$ the union of two planes of $\mathbb C^4$ intersecting at the origin and let $\mathbb Z_2$ act by identifying the two planes via any linear isomorphism. $X$ is affine and behaves as Dan's example.

Comment: @rita but $X$ is not irreducible in that case and this is also an important hypothesis for me...

Comment: I forgot irreducible, sorry!

Comment: @Dan and somehow I do not quite understand your argument that it does not matter that you glue after of before quotienting. It seems to me that it would imply that there is a commutative triangle involving $\mathbb{C}^2−0$, $X$ and $\mathbb{C}^2−0$ with maps being the quotient by $\mathbb{Z}_2$, the quotient by the equivalence relation and again the quotient by $\mathbb{Z}_2$ (once descended to $X$). But this commutative triangle would show that the fiber of $X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^2-0$ has length 1 over the image of $(1,1)=(−1,−1)$. This is impossible by semi-continuity.

Comment: @Libli Here's a different attempt at proving quasi-projectivity. Suppose that some large degree Veronese embedding of $\mathbb P^2$ has the property that a unique secant line passes through a general point of its secant variety. Then projection from that point will identify these two points and no others. Presumably this is known classically but one reference is http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0502344

Comment: Also, I don't understand your length argument. The same argument would prove e.g. that the quotient of $\{xy=0\} \subset \mathbb C^2$ by $\mathbb Z/2$ is not a line, which is nonsense.

Comment: @DanPetersen OK for quasi-projectivity. But I still persist with my length argument. 
I don't really see the connection with $xy = 0 \subset \mathbb{C}^2$ (because the length of the fiber over $0$ must be at least $2$ in that example). I am just saying that if the quotient of $\mathbb{C}^2-0$ by $Z_2$ factors through $X$, then the fiber of the map $X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^2-0$ over the image of $(1,1) = (-1,-1)$ must be of length one (because the fiber of the map $\mathbb{C}^2-0 \rightarrow X$ over $(1,1) = (-1,-1)$ is 2 distinct points). This is impossible by semi-continuity.