# generalization Abhyankar's lemma

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, singularity-theory

This question is related to a question I already asked on MO ([smooth quotient out of a singular variety?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/173538/smooth-quotient-out-of-a-singular-variety)), but I realized later that the hypotheses where not precise enough in my former question.

Let $p : X \rightarrow Y$ be a finite morphism of algebraic varieties over $\mathbb{C}$ with $Y$ smooth and $X$ normal.
By Abhyankar's theorem, we know that if the ramification locus of $p$ is a divisor with normal crossings, then $X$ has quotient singularities (and in particular has rational singularities).

I would like to know if there are weaker hypotheses on the ramification locus which would imply that $X$ is Cohen-Macaulay? One important thing is that I don't want to assume that $p$ is flat (in fact I want to prove that $p$ is flat).

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please give a reference for Abhyankar's result?

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi There is this paper by Viehweg : https://www.uni-due.de/~mat903/preprints/ec/rational_sing.pdf (lemma 2). But he does not prove it, he gives a reference to a paper in German, which I am not able to read.

Comment: @FrancoPolizzi It's in SGA 1 XII.5.2.

Comment: @WillSawin: thanks. Maybe you meant SGA 1 XIII.5.2?

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi yes, sorry for my mistake.